# webVR starter kit: how to make a focus point in Panoramic Viewer

Tags: webvr

I am trying to build a VR tour using WebVR starter kit:

[Web VR Starter Kit](https://github.com/povdocs/webvr-starter-kit)

Web VR Starter Kit is a Javascript library for easily creating virtual reality content and making it available in web browsers on a range of devices. The library includes a simplified API for creating an manipulating 3D objects.

[My Code on JS bin](https://jsbin.com/mawisa/edit?html,js,output)

```
var mark1 = VR.torus({radius:0.2,
           tube:0.01,
           color:"#efe2a2",
           });

var focus = VR.torus({radius:0.02,
           tube:0.01,
           color:"white",
           });

var img1 = "//i.imgur.com/Rp4hJKX.jpg?1";
var img2 = "http://blog.topazlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Screen-Shot-2013-12-11-at-10.42.18-AM.png"
var img3 = "https://i1.wp.com/www.samrohn.com/wp-content/uploads/tobacco-warehouse-panorama.jpg?fit=1000%2C500";
var imgs = [img1, img2, img3];
var i = 0;

mark1.moveTo(0,0,0);
focus.moveTo(0,1.5,0);
focus.parent=VR.body;

VR.panorama(imgs[i]);

VR.on('lookat', function(target){
    if (target === mark1.object)
        i = (i+1)%3;
        VR.vibrate(250);
        VR.panorama(imgs[i]);
    });
```

If the player is looking at mark1, VR panoramic image will switch to the next.I try to create a focus point that indicate where the player is looking at. but I don't know how to parent the focus object (small white torus) to the camera.

Answer (score 0):

```
var focus = VR.camera.torus({radius:0.02,
       tube:0.01,
       color:"white",
       });
```

This is the way to create a child from the parent camera.

var focus = VR.camera.torus